# Struggling to make embedded videos fit vertically on top of each other (Responsive design)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am having some issues with designing the responsive part of a project I am currently working on. I am trying to make the content section stack ontop of each other for optimal mobile viewing experience however, it seems to lay it out horizontally which is how it is on the desktop version but is not needed for mobile. I have placed the embedded YouTube videos in the relevant CSS grid too, I am just asking if someone can help me with a solution to get the CSS grid to vertically align on top of each other along with all the embedded videos.

Please take a look below for the code snippets in the discussion here.

I have tried to use the CSS grid property `grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax());` but so far have failed to get the boxes to stack vertically along with the content being contained within the CSS grid boxes.

```css
/* CSS code below */

.css-grid>div {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 1em;
}

.css-grid>div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #fff;
}

.css-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2fr 2fr 2fr;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(14rem, 1fr));
}

.black-girl-hair {
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 5%;
  color: #1f1f20;
}

.dime {
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  bottom: 1fr;
  border-radius: 5%;
  color: #1f1f20
}

.hatrick {
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #1f1f20;
  text-align: left;
  border-radius: 5%;
}

.contact-info {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 60px;
}
```

```html
/* HTML code below */
<section class="middle" id="Content">

  <h3>Content</h3>
  <div class="css-grid">
    <div class="black-girl-hair">
      <p>Check out Black Girl Hair: Embarrassed Proud or Shy, where I-S-H provides a platform to many women who were marginalised previously.</p>
      <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Eq5rtp-Oni0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="dime">
      <p>U.K. Dime</p>
      <iframe width="360" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Jxm8f8OVJLM" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>

    <div class="hatrick">
      <p>Listen to Hat-Trick (available on all streaming platforms) where I-S-H captures the essence of summer on a cool-vibes instrumental.</p>

      <iframe src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/album/3GgYHq8f2ktVFBzmRUtbel" width="250" height="200" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>

      <a href="https://geo.itunes.apple.com/gb/album/hat-trick/1463966142?i=1463966143&mt=1&app=music" style="display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;background:url(https://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com/en-us/badge-lrg.svg?releaseDate=2019-05-10&kind=song&bubble=apple_music) no-repeat;width:158px;height:45px;"></a>


    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You can try to change to `<iframe width="100%"`, and remove the height. Also you will need to set a height for the `p:nth-child(1)`; for example: 130px and `overflow:scroll`

Comment: Thank you for that guidance I have now resolved the issue